# phpMyAdmin designer for showing specific tables only - is this possible?

Tags: phpmyadmin, designer

I want to see the relations to the table `mdl_user` in Moodle's database but when I open the designer in `phpMyAdmin` it shows all the tables and makes it almost impossible to find it in all 200+ tables.

Is there a way to restrict the number of tables in Designer View?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the toolbar of the designer click the leftmost button(`Show/Hide left menu` button). It will open the left menu which will have all the tables listed with a checkbox against each of them. You can choose tables to hide by unchecking corresponding checkboxes. Left menu also have buttons to `Hide/Show all` and `Hide/Show tables with no relations`.